# Protractor tests are not running in gitlab-ci after Google Chrome updated to version 75 yesterday. It worked before the update. What happened?

Tags: docker-compose, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

I am running a scheduled job in gitlab to run protractor tests on an application on Google Chrome. These tests were working along nicely until yesterday June 04, 2019 where Google updated chrome from version 74 to version 75. Now I am getting a "W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response" issue since the update.

This is run on the gitlab ci environment. I don't use webdriver-manager, my team really needs me to use docker-compose to create a selenium grid. I don't really know where to start fixing this issue.

```
test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apk add py-pip
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install docker-compose==1.23.2
    - docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY_USER -p $DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
    - echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=\${NPM_HAVENBUILD_AUTH_TOKEN}" > .npmrc
    - npm install
    - npm config set unsafe-perm true
    - npm install -g protractor
    - npm install -g protractor-console
    - npm config set unsafe-perm falsesh
    - ./node_modules/.bin/gulp

  script:
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker-compose scale chrome=2
    - ./node_modules/.bin/protractor TestFiles/HConf.js --suite client --testname  Happy_Path --env uat
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
[19:53:28] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://docker-dind:4444/wd/hub
[19:53:28] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {
  "value": {
    "sessionId": "d8b6ab9a6e301a943203e8af49aec285",
    "capabilities": {
      "acceptInsecureCerts": false,
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "browserVersion": "75.0.3770.80",
      "chrome": {
        "chromedriverVersion": "75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs\u002fbranch-heads\u002f3770@{#40})",
        "userDataDir": "\u002ftmp\u002f.com.google.Chrome.zQzfpf"
      },
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "debuggerAddress": "localhost:46326"
      },
      "networkConnectionEnabled": false,
      "pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
      "platformName": "linux",
      "proxy": {
      },
      "setWindowRect": true,
      "strictFileInteractability": false,
      "timeouts": {
        "implicit": 0,
        "pageLoad": 300000,
        "script": 30000
      },
      "unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify",
      "webdriver.remote.sessionid": "d8b6ab9a6e301a943203e8af49aec285"
    }
  }
}
[19:53:28] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
```

I am suppose to have the protractor tests run insead of this after it starts using the selenium server.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: you could downgrade your chrome back to older version or try updating chromedriver